# Wordpress Menu - Active Class Not Working

Tags: wordpress

I'm changing the style of a WordPress theme 'Invert'.

For some reason the active class in the menu works fine for each web (it has a background blue property) page except for the sub pages of the blog. Which you can see here.

```
http://www.branchingouteurope.com/BOE2014/
http://www.branchingouteurope.com/BOE2014/
http://www.branchingouteurope.com/BOE2014/blog/
http://www.branchingouteurope.com/BOE2014/blog/lead-generation-app-of-the-month-jan/
```

The styles linked to the menu are as follows in the style sheet:

```
#skenav ul li.current_page_item > a,
#skenav ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#skenav ul li.current-menu-item > a,
#skenav ul li.current-menu-parent > a { background-color:<?php if(isset($bg_color)){ echo $bg_color; } ?>;color:#fff;}
```

Any help here would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The styles which apply the background currently target the class **.current_page_item** - so just the current page. To apply it to the sub-pages as well, also target **.current_page_parent** with the same styles, like this:

```
#skenav ul li.current_page_item > a, #skenav ul li.current_page_parent > a, #skenav ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a, #skenav ul li.current-menu-item > a, #skenav ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
    background-color: #17bfdc;
    color: #fff;
}
```

These classes should be added out of the box (just checked with invert lite). But you can use a filter to add a class yourself to the blog menu in single blog posts like this:

```
function add_page_parent_to_single( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( is_single() && $item->title == 'Blog' ) {
        $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_page_parent_to_single', 10, 2 );
```

Although it's work around - I don't really like referencing a menu by name like that.

Comment: I've tried to add the .current_page_parent class to the stylesheet as you suggested, however it doesn't seem to have changed anything. I might be doing this wrong. I found out that the CSS file that changed the menu wasn't the standard 'style' CSS file but within a PHP file found here http://www.branchingouteurope.com/BOE2014/wp-content/themes/invert/includes/invert-custom-css.php

Comment: Strange that those classes aren't being applied now. Are you using the standard Wordpress menu system? And is there any other code modifying it?

Comment: I'm using the standard Wordpress menu system. What is odd is that the 'services' sub pages seem to apply the parent style to the menu eg [link](http://www.branchingouteurope.com/BOE2014/services/discover/) it's only on the 'blog' sub pages that the parent page style isn't applied.

Comment: Posts aren't sub-pages in the same sense as the others, but they should still have that class - I checked with a vanilla install of Invert lite and it did not have the same problem. Possibly something else is affecting the menu - I've updated the above with a filter which you could use to add the class as a work-around.

Comment: I've added that function and it's worked. Thank you! Must have been something I've done. Wish I knew as much about front end code as you do. Very much appreciated. I'm always trying to learn more about front end dev every day - what are the downsides of referencing a menu by name?

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. The downside is that if you chose to rename that menu item, you would have to update the function as well to keep the styling.